# How to edit/delete a row from a database in a modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have an html table that holds many clients I have stored in a database. I have it setup that I can create a client with a modal on the same screen. This works great. I also put a little pencil and "x" icon at the end of each row. I want to be able to edit the row when I click on the pencil and delete the row when I click the X. I have it working that when I click on the icons, a corresponding modal opens, but I do not know how to keep track of which row it is that needs to be edited or deleted. I would like the form information in the edit modal to load when I click the pencil and the modal opens. If I did not use a modal I know I could simply use an `@Html.ActionLink` and pass the row's ID but I do not know how to get that from a modal.

I know there are similar questions out there already, many of which which I have already tried to no avail. Here is all my code from my view that is relevant. I am also using Twiiter Bootstrap MVC helper methods from https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    @using (var table=Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Table().Striped()))
    {            
        <tr>
            @foreach (SelectListItem field in ViewBag.Fields)
            {
                <th>@field.Text</th>
            }
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        foreach(CPS.Models.Client client in ViewBag.Clients)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@client.firstName</td>
                <td>@client.lastName</td>
                <td>@client.mobileNumber</td>
                <td>@client.homeNumber</td>
                <td>@client.email</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Href("#EditModal")" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@client.id">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Edit.png")">
                    </a> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Href("#DeleteModal")" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@client.id" >
                        <img id="img_logo" alt="Logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Delete.png")"/>
                    </a>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</div>
</div>
@*Modals*@
@using (var modal = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new         Modal().Id("CreateClientModal").Closeable()))
{
    @modal.Header("Create New Client")
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    using (modal.BeginBody())
    {
    using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form().LabelWidthLg(3).LabelWidthSm(1)))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.mobileNumber)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.homeNumber)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.email)
        using (modal.BeginFooter())
        {
            @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton())
        }
    }
}

}

@using (var modal = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Modal().Id("EditModal").Closeable()))
{
    @modal.Header("Edit Client")
    using (modal.BeginBody())
    {
        using (var f = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form().LabelWidthLg(3).LabelWidthSm(1)))
        {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.mobileNumber)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.homeNumber)
        @f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.email)
        using (modal.BeginFooter())
        {
            @f.FormGroup().CustomControls(Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton())
        }
    }
}
}

@using (var modal = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Modal().Id("DeleteModal").Closeable()))
{

    @modal.Header(" Client")
    using (modal.BeginBody())
    {
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete the selected client?</p>
    }
    using (modal.BeginFooter())
    {
        @Html.Bootstrap().ActionLinkButton("Yes","Clients")
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Is it possible to pass the ID via the routing which brings up the modal?

Comment: Can you not just stick a hidden field in each of the forms, and populate it with the id of the current row before showing the modal?

Comment: Maybe, I do not know, thats why I am asking. How would I do that?